# Select configfile during installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, setup-project

Is it possible to add a custom buildaction which allows the user to select the wanted configfilesettings during installation?

My issue is that I have a large configfile (and logfile) which currently includes settings for developmentmachines, testenvironments, stagingenvironments and production. I would like the installer to ask me (for example through a dropdownlist) which environment I want to install for and then select the correct settings.

I have previously used TT-files to generate multiple files specified for different environment from a "master config file" with all settings defined, so this would work. The problem then is that I get multiple configfiles as output and then have to rename the correct one back to the "real configfiles name" (for exampe from web.config.prod back to web.config) and then delete all the others..

If anyone have some good pointers or resources on this I would really appriciate it!

Comment: Do you truly mean *install* time? Everything about your question seems to indicate build time. If the latter, I can post a solution that might be helpful.